# Get attribute value without name of attribute with xml2 in R

Tags: r, data.table, xml2

I have an R script that takes xml nodes from a website and gets the attributes. However, when I convert to data.table, the names of the attributes are added to their values. The code is:

```
lnk = "https://iati.fcdo.gov.uk/iati_files/Region/FCDO-Developing-countries-unspecified-998-2.xml"

link = read_xml(lnk)
  tvalnodes = link %>% xml_find_all("//transaction/value")
  tattr     = data.table(tvalnodes %>% html_attrs)
              tattr[, c("currency","date") := tstrsplit(V1, ",", fixed=TRUE)]
```

Which sort of does what I want, but in the columns currency and date, the values are (e.g. `c(currency = "GBP"` instead of simply `"GBP"`. i.e.

So I get :

```
                  V1           currency                          date
   1: GBP,2010-05-19 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2010-05-19")
   2: GBP,2010-05-24 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2010-05-24")
   3: GBP,2010-10-15 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2010-10-15")
   4: GBP,2010-12-16 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2010-12-16")
   5: GBP,2011-03-21 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2011-03-21")
  ---                                                                
9684: GBP,2014-10-10 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2014-10-10")
9685: GBP,2011-02-11 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2011-02-11")
9686: GBP,2011-10-10 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2011-10-10")
9687: GBP,2011-03-24 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2011-03-24")
9688: GBP,2011-03-25 c(currency = "GBP"  `value-date` = "2011-03-25")
```

instead of:

```
                  V1 currency       date
   1: GBP,2010-05-19      GBP 2010-05-19
   2: GBP,2010-05-24      GBP 2010-05-24
   3: GBP,2010-10-15      GBP 2010-10-15
   4: GBP,2010-12-16      GBP 2010-12-16
   5: GBP,2011-03-21      GBP 2011-03-21
  ---                                   
9684: GBP,2014-10-10      GBP 2014-10-10
9685: GBP,2011-02-11      GBP 2011-02-11
9686: GBP,2011-10-10      GBP 2011-10-10
9687: GBP,2011-03-24      GBP 2011-03-24
9688: GBP,2011-03-25      GBP 2011-03-25
```

It's not too difficult to get rid of all the mess with gsub, but there must be a way of doing this without all the clutter. I'm very keen to use data.table because I need to do this on a lot of files and it is much faster than what I had been doing (bind_rows from dplyr).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rbind`:

```
as.data.table(do.call(rbind,html_attrs(tvalnodes)))

      currency value-date
   1:      GBP 2010-05-19
   2:      GBP 2010-05-24
   3:      GBP 2010-10-15
   4:      GBP 2010-12-16
   5:      GBP 2011-03-21
  ---
```